# Hardware for software tracking please

Tags: ios, iphone-app

I am going to purchase a MAC, to implement analytics tracking on IOS apps.

Does any one can tell me the hardware recommendations?
Like 256GB space, 16GB ram etc? Is it sufficient?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not *hardware* – so this seems off-topic. For details, please refer to [Are hardware recommendations on-topic?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/112/185) You might wish to check with our [Hardware Recommendations](//hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Pri, but you are very much on the wrong site here. We only recommend software application here (so, please don’t get discouraged when this question gets closed, maybe even downvoted. Please, do come back and ask us to recommend software apps). In fact, I am not really sure which S.E site you could ask on.

It sound like you are looking for a server. Generally, I would use a desktop, just because it would be much cheaper than a laptop. If you are really on a budget, use Linux, rather than Windows and note that Mac hardware is generally more expensive.

How much disk space you need depends on how much data you will store, but you can calculate that by simple arithmetic.

E.g each measurement requires X bytes to store and you will be tracking Y devices every Z minutes/hours.

16gB should be fine, unless you will add ***many*** records per second. If it is no more than a few dozen every second, then the amount of RAM is probably defined by your choice of operating system, as the database access will add little processing.

I will presume that you know some database (MySql, Sqlite, etc) and a server side programming language, such as PHP or Node.Js. You also need to be able to code Swift for a native iOs app, or JS (I recommend AngularJs) for a browser based app. Consider browser based in case you might ever want to track Androids or Windows 10 based devices.

Don’t forget the usual stuff like security, using HTTPS, sanitizing user input (even if it *is* AJAX), backing up your database, etc